# Display an excel file, which user can accept or not

Tags: android, xls, startactivityforresult

I need to display an Excel file that I created. What I need now is to display the .xls file to the user to see it, along with an "Accept" button and a "Cancel" button. I know I can create an Intent for the phone to open the file, but it will open in another app, and I will not be able to create that buttons.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

PS: im doing it via startActivityForResult.

Comment: Do you want to show all the content in excel file to user?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the user the Excel, but will not be able to modify it.

Comment: If it's not that large, you can use table layout to display data as like excel